# How to permanently disable "Waves' MaxxAudio Pro" / MaxxSense

Tags: windows, audio

How to permanently disable "Waves' MaxxAudio Pro" / MaxxSense?

Because if you close it (Dell Audio in this case but it may be the same with all Realtek equipped workstations) and reopen it from systray again it will be enabled again. Also if you restart your computer it will be enabled again or if you plug in earphones or something. It's a Windows 10 workstation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My (poor) workaround is to leave it enabled, but disable all the individual components inside a preset called "Off":

[image: Disable all settings]

This is not a default preset, just match the settings I have above and then click the Disk/Save icon...it will prompt you to name the new preset.  I could not figure out a way to permanently turn it off.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I am not able to give it a try right now.. does it sound (neutral) like if it would be disabled?

Comment: As best as I can tell, yes.  My equip here is probably not good enough to tell the difference.

Comment: How do you access this `Dell Audio` program in your screen-shot?

Comment: @PeterX it´s accessible via clicking it´s icon in systray

Answer (score 5):

Simply uninstall Waves MaxxAudio Pro.

> Start Menu > Waves MaxxAudio Pro > right click > uninstall.  Worked for me.

Or, you could change the audio driver from Realtek to Microsoft, which also worked for me, but this seems a bit heavy handed:

> Device Manger > Sound, Video, and game controllers > RealTek Audio > Update Driver > Browse my computer for driver software > Let me pick from a list of available drivers on my computer > Uncheck Show compatible hardware > Manufacturer > Microsoft > High Definition Audio Device Version {latest} > OK

Comment: I tried uninstalling it from the start menu, but it went to the Uninstall or change a program menu, in Control Panel.  There was no program by that name in the list. That said, turning everything off still works.

Comment: This only works if you go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Realtek\Audio\Waves` after installing the Realtek driver provided by Dell. Click on the x64 or x86 version of the program depending on your system. If you use this method Maxx Audio shows up in the "Uninstall a program" list.

Comment: In 2022, the option of changing the audio driver to Microsoft's latest High Definition Audio Device driver worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't uninstall the msu I found:

```
get-package *maxx* | ft -a

Name                                            Version Source ProviderName
----                                            ------- ------ ------------
9PJPPGG8TGVG-WavesAudio.MaxxAudioProforDell2019                msu
```

But I can uninstall the windows app, and disable an autorun that makes a redundant shortcut in the user profile start menu.

```
$list = 'WavesAudio.MaxxAudioProforDell2019'
foreach ($app in $list) { 
  Get-AppxPackage $app -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
  dir "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\$app*"  # verify it's gone
}

# not work, does this install the driver?
#uninstall-package 9PJPPGG8TGVG-WavesAudio.MaxxAudioProforDell2019 -provider msu

# autorun makes extra .lnk shortcut under user profile
# this is like unchecking something in sysinternals autoruns
if (! (test-path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\AutorunsDisabled)) { 
  new-item HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\AutorunsDisabled }
move-itemproperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\AutorunsDisabled WavesSvc
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. Go the the folder: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Realtek\Audio\Waves`
2. Double-click `Maxx Audio Installer (x64).msi`
3. Choose "Remove" and OK
4. Restart PC

Comment: Doesn't exist in my case, but the Maxx thing still does. Thanks however, could work for some!

Comment: Same with me. Doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10
You can use [Bulk Crap uninstaller](https://www.bcuninstaller.com/) to remove Waves MaxxAudio Pro / MaxxSense software including the registry keys (do not delete low confidence keys and be sure to make a backup of registry) followed by the procedure

***WORKAROUND 1 :***

> Right click on start -> Device manager -> Audio inputs and outputs ->
> Speakers -> Update Drivers -> Browse my drivers -> Let me Pick from
> Installed

Now If you find ***High Definition Audio*** in it choose the driver and reboot the system for the changes to take place, If not then refer **WORKAROUND 2**

***WORKAROUND 2 :***

> Go to Settings -> Update and Security -> Troubleshoot -> Additional
> Troubleshooters -> Playing Audio -> Run Troubleshooter -> Choose the
> speaker

Now very important,

> When you are prompted with ***Turn off Sound effects and Audio
> enhancements***   Choose *Yes Open Audio Enhancement*

This will open a Properties Window

> Go to General Tab -> Controller Information -> Properties In the
> properties dialog box -> Driver -> Update Drivers -> Browse my drivers
> -> Let me Pick from Installed

Choose ***High Definition Audio*** Driver and reboot the system for the changes to take place.

Now the key takeaway is to put the **High Definition Audio** to be your Default Driver in order for the Speaker and headphone jack to work seamlessly (i.e detecting the plug in and out of headphones).

Comment: Workaround 2 was the only way that worked for me on Windows 11 X-Lite. However, as the troubleshooters are deprecated, there's an easier way: Go into Settings > System > Sound > More sound settings. Right click speakers, click "Properties", then the properties button in the next window. Click "Change settings", then the driver tab, then "Update Driver" and go from there as above.

Comment: @NoodleCollie I have tried these on windows 10 home version which contains troubleshooter but hey it's coool that you have added a workaround for lite version!